# VHDL weird bit errors seemingly makes no sense

Tags: arrays, vhdl, bit, fpga

I have a Micro-Nova FPGA dev board with a Xilinx Spartan-3A.  I am trying to make it communicate bits over GPIO on a raspberry pi using 3 pins: REQ, ACK, DATA.  The code works fine if I uncomment the bit_data assignments and comment out "bit_data := data_out(data_ofs);" and on the Pi i get a continous 10101010... etc.  But if I leave the code as pasted below I get the wrong bits at random times eg. 1010110100... etc.

Any idea what could be the problem?:

**VHDL on FPGA:**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity xclock is

Port(CLK : in STD_LOGIC;
     REQ : in STD_LOGIC;
     ACK : out STD_LOGIC;
     DATA : out STD_LOGIC);

end xclock;

architecture Behavioral of xclock is

begin

    process(CLK)

        variable data_ofs : integer range 0 to 2 := 0;
        variable data_out : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0) := "01";
        variable bit_data : std_logic := '0';
        variable ack_data : std_logic := '0';
        variable LASTREQ : std_logic := '0';
        variable seconds : integer range 0 to 50000000 := 0;
        variable tick : integer range 0 to 50000000 := 0;

    begin

        if CLK'event and CLK = '1' then

            tick := tick + 1;
            if tick = 49999999 then
                tick := 0;
                seconds := seconds + 1;
                if seconds = 49999999 then
                    seconds := 0;
                end if;
            end if;

            if seconds > 1 then
                if REQ /= LASTREQ and REQ /= ack_data then
                    LASTREQ := REQ;
                    if REQ = '1' then
                        --bit_data := '1';
                        ack_data := '1';
                    else
                        --bit_data := '0';
                        ack_data := '0';
                    end if;
                    bit_data := data_out(data_ofs);
                    data_ofs := data_ofs + 1;
                    if data_ofs = 2 then
                        data_ofs := 0;
                    end if;
                end if;
            end if;

            DATA <= bit_data;
            ACK <= ack_data;

        end if;

    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

**Bash script on Pi:**

```
REQ=27
ACK=17
DATA=22

gpio -g mode $REQ out
gpio -g mode $ACK in
gpio -g mode $DATA in
gpio -g write $REQ 1

e=1

while [ 1 ]; do
  while [ 1 ]; do
    if [ `gpio -g read $ACK` -eq 1 ]; then
        while [ 1 ]; do
            d=`gpio -g read $DATA`
            echo $d
            if [ $d -ne $e ]; then
                echo error DATA should be $e
                sleep 1
            else
                if [ $e -eq 0 ]; then
                    e=1
                else
                    e=0
                fi
                break
            fi
        done
        gpio -g write $REQ 0
        break;
    fi
  done
  while [ 1 ]; do
    if [ `gpio -g read $REQ` -eq 0 ]; then
        while [ 1 ]; do
            d=`gpio -g read $DATA`
            echo $d
            if [ $d -ne $e ]; then
                echo error DATA should be $e
                sleep 1
            else
                if [ $e -eq 0 ]; then
                    e=1
                else
                    e=0
                fi
                break
            fi
        done
        gpio -g write $REQ 1
        break;
    fi
    sleep 1
    done
  done
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Pulling my hair out on this one!

Comment: Without getting into detail of what the code should be doing, it sounds like a [metastability](https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/wp/wp-01082-quartus-ii-metastability.pdf) issue. E.g. you are using some of the top modules input signals in a clocked process without any synchronization. Your VHDL coding style is also very "C-ish".

Comment: if metastability is the case why does it get triggered by using bit_data := data_out(data_ofs);?  and how can I get around this issue?  also how would this be written "VHDL-ish"?

Comment: One of the main reason you have issues with your design is that you are using variables in a way that many of the logic in your code are implemented in latches. The rule of thumb when writing code for fpga fpgais to avoid using variables.

Comment: Have you simulated your design? Does it work as you would expect in simulation?

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time trying to figure out how your code is supposed to work (what the protocol is), but I gave up. Building off what other have suggested, you might try to make the following modifications and see if it makes any difference.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity xclock is

port(CLK : in STD_LOGIC;
     REQ : in STD_LOGIC;
     ACK : out STD_LOGIC;
     DATA : out STD_LOGIC);

end xclock;

architecture Behavioral of xclock is

   signal req_reg1, req_reg2, req_int, last_req : std_logic := '0';
   signal bit_data_reg, ack_reg                 : std_logic;

begin

    process(CLK)

        variable data_ofs : integer range 0 to 2 := 0;
        variable data_out : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0) := "01";
        variable bit_data : std_logic := '0';
        variable ack_data : std_logic := '0';
        variable seconds : integer range 0 to 50000000 := 0;
        variable tick : integer range 0 to 50000000 := 0;

    begin

        if CLK'event and CLK = '1' then

            -- Input registers help prevent metastability on REQ line
            -- Note that if there is significant bounce or glitching, then
            -- you will also need a deglitcher.
            req_reg1 <= REQ;
            req_reg2 <= req_reg1;
            req_int  <= req_reg2;

            tick := tick + 1;
            if tick = 49999999 then
                tick := 0;
                seconds := seconds + 1;
                if seconds = 49999999 then
                    seconds := 0;
                end if;
            end if;

            if seconds > 1 then
                -- Using the registered inputs instead of the direct REQ input.
                if req_int /= last_req and req_int /= ack_data then
                    last_req <= req_int;
                    if req_int = '1' then
                        ack_data := '1';
                    else
                        ack_data := '0';
                    end if;
                    bit_data := data_out(data_ofs);
                    data_ofs := data_ofs + 1;
                    if data_ofs = 2 then
                        data_ofs := 0;
                    end if;
                end if;
            end if;

            -- Register outputs to ensure consistent OREG packing, if enabled
            bit_data_reg <= bit_data;
            ack_reg      <= ack_data;

            DATA         <= bit_data_reg;
            ACK          <= ack_reg;

        end if;

    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

The modifications to the code do two things:

- Register the input REQ a couple times to reduce the probability of metastability, and then only use the registered values instead of the pin itself. ([Read more](https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/wp/wp-01082-quartus-ii-metastability.pdf))
- Register the outputs (twice) to ensure that the output register can be placed in an OREG (in IOB), which ensures consistent clock-to-out timing at the output pad. At the boundaries of your device, when possible, it is nice to place a plain FF register stage which guarantees that packing into OREG is possible. Otherwise there may be a feedback path from last register stage back into your design which prevents packing.